# Error creating a new project on Android Studio (Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

when I try to create a new project on Android Studio (Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2), I get this error:

[image]

Here is my gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

and my settings.gradle :

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "TestProject"
include ':app'
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem? I am completely paralyzed due to this error and have tried all the other solutions found in StackOverflow and elsewhere, but all in vain.

Comment: share your setting.gradle

Comment: Check your gradle-wrapper.properties file distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip

Comment: Check your settings.gradle as well `pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
`

Comment: @JinalPatel I made the changes but it didn't work either.

Comment: @Manjeetdeswal Just added my settings.gradle to the post

Comment: Text is better than pictures of text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418 That is why I undid your last edit. Feel free to show pictures in addition to text, but not instead.

Comment: Try changing the version from 7.1.2 to 7.0.2 and invalidate cache and restart. Also check if you have Gradle jdk -> 11

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to the internet and to the steps as Picture is shown below. If this doesn't solve your problem, please do let me know.

**Step - File --> Sync Project with Gradle Files**

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@Talia Your settings.gradle file should look like,

```
  pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            gradlePluginPortal()
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
        
    rootProject.name = "My Application"
    include ':app'
```

Replace with above and set your project name as rootProject.name

Comment: Updated my post with the changed settings.gradle. Still, not working...

Comment: @Talia Have you replaced entire settings.gradle with above and synced with gradle?

Comment: We don't need any extra code in settings.gradle file you can replace with above

Comment: Yeah, I did that both on the previous project and a new one. But the changes that I added to my post were undone by StackOverflow's editors. So check my post again to see the new settings.gradle which is just the copy of your code.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade from 7.1.2 to 7.0.2 Helped me.

id 'com.android.application' version '7.0.2' apply false

id 'com.android.library' version '7.0.2' apply false